# Missing comma in insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an insert statmement which wont execute due to a missing comma error.

```
INSERT INTO trip 
VALUES (01, TO_DATE('28-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy', '29-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy', '28-Jan-2022 7:10:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss', '29-Jan-2022 9:30:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss', 0, 200, 20, 'SANFDAE11U1286116', 34, 34, 'AUS00101', 01 );
```

Can you help me find it?
Thankyou.

Comment: Start with the missing `)`.

Comment: don't use a leading zero with `01`

Comment: The to_date function does not have a closing bracket

Comment: I guess you want `TO_DATE(date1, format1), TO_DATE(date2, format2), TO_DATE(...)...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you got an error because you did not close function `TO_DATE`, so you need to add `)`.
This statement would work without error, maybe.

```
INSERT INTO trip VALUES (01, TO_DATE('28-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), TO_DATE('29-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), TO_DATE('28-Jan-2022 7:10:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('29-Jan-2022 9:30:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'), 0, 200, 20, 'SANFDAE11U1286116', 34, 34, 'AUS00101', 01 );
```

I don't know what `AUS00101`, `SANFDAE11U1286116`... means, but anyway the problem is opening and closing brackets.

Also, `TO_DATE` is known to be capable of only 1 date.

Comment: Really - is to_date capable of taking more than 1 date?

Comment: (fixed, `DO_DATE()` can take only one date and its format) @P.Salmon

Answer (score 1):

Each string requires its own `TO_DATE`

Additionally,

- `01` is a string; you should enclose it into single quotes; without them, you'll enter a number, `1` (leading zero will be lost)
- name **all columns** in `INSERT`; you'll easily get confused if you specify just values to be inserted. Something like my *dummy* example (as I don't know real column names):

---

```
INSERT INTO trip (id,
                  start_date,
                  end_date,
                  date_1,
                  date_2,
                  ping,
                  pong,
                  attr,
                  string_value,
                  num1,
                  num2,
                  country,
                  code)
     VALUES ('01',
             TO_DATE ('28-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),
             TO_DATE ('29-Jan-2022', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'),
             TO_DATE ('28-Jan-2022 7:10:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'),
             TO_DATE ('29-Jan-2022 9:30:00', 'dd-Mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss'),
             0,
             200,
             20,
             'SANFDAE11U1286116',
             34,
             34,
             'AUS00101',
             '01');
```